# How can I use the {:<#} string alignment with a variable lenght (instead of #)?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I want to print some data on a left justification (alignment) but the spacing might need to change in real-time before printing so I would like to use a variable instead of a fixed hard-coded space width.

I tried using a variable to hold the number of spaces but that does work:

```
string_alignment_spacing = 15
print("|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|".format('Butter', 'Toast', 'Gravy'))
```

I was hoping to get the following output:

```
|Butter         |Toast          |Gravy         |
```

But instead get:

```
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `string_alignment_spacing` inside `{}` and in the `format()` method set keyword argument `string_alignment_spacing=string_alignment_spacing`:

```
string_alignment_spacing = 15
print("|{:<{string_alignment_spacing}}|{:<{string_alignment_spacing}}|{:<{string_alignment_spacing}}|".format('Butter', 'Toast', 'Gravy', string_alignment_spacing=string_alignment_spacing))
```

Prints:

```
|Butter         |Toast          |Gravy          |
```

EDIT (With f-strings):

```
string_alignment_spacing = 15
print(f'|{"Butter":<{string_alignment_spacing}}|{"Toast":<{string_alignment_spacing}}|{"Gravy":<{string_alignment_spacing}}|')
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the following code,string_alignment_spacing is only str and there's an illegal space behind it.**

```
print("|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|{:<string_alignment_spacing }|".format('Butter', 'Toast', 'Gravy'))
```

**Try the following code**

```
formatstr = "|{:<%s}|{:<%s}|{:<%s}|"%(15,15,15)
print(formatstr.format('Butter', 'Toast', 'Gravy'))
```